# richtext editor edited content pass to another controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, rich-text-editor, richtextediting

I'm having following controller action to load rich text editor in a page

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {            

        Editor Editor1 = new Editor(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, "Editor1");            

        Editor1.LoadHtml("~/brochuretemplates/myhtml.html");

        Editor1.MvcInit();

        ViewBag.Editor = Editor1.MvcGetString();

        return View();
    }
```

Initially above function load **.HTML** file to richtext editor content that contains inside the project.

Once HTML file loaded, I can do changes of that content. this is the initial view of that

[image]

this is the changed view of that rich text editor content

[image]

I want to pass that changed content to another method how can I do that

Comment: How are you posting the data? What is the method you posting it back to?

Comment: Actually this is only code snippet I'm using to load this Rich text editor , no post method using

Comment: You have sent it from the server to the client. if you want it back again, you need to post it :) - either submit a form, or using ajax

Comment: @StephenMuecke I followed this documentation to configure this http://richtexteditor.com/document/ `Installation > Using RTE in ASP.NET MVC`

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you give me little example

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that plugin. Do you currently have a form in the view?

Comment: Nope In my View I have only following syntax to load richtext editor  `<div > @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Editor) </div>` no `<form>` tag

Comment: You will need a form containing your editor and a submit button so you can post back the content of the editor.